# Create new column with if condition in dataframe Pyton

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have the following dataset in python dataframe:

| id | updated hobby | old hoby | updated skill | old skill |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cricket | Soccer | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | Cricket | Cricket | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | Basketball | Soccer | 3 | 3 |

I have tried doing it with a new column and if statement but I am not that good with Python so got bunch of errors.

I want the following output:

| id | updated hobby | old hoby | updated skill | old skill | columns updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cricket | Soccer | 4 | 3 | Hobby, Skill |
| 2 | Cricket | Cricket | 3 | 3 | No update |
| 3 | Basketball | Soccer | 3 | 3 | Hobby |

I want to get the list of columns that were updated when compared to the value of old values so if the updated value column has changed then I want to capture that in the columns updated column. If nothing has changed then No update needs to be stored.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some straightforward solution using `pd.Dataframe.apply` method and helper function:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["updated_hobby", "old_hobby", "updated_skill", "old_skill"],
    data=[
        ("Cricket", "Soccer", 4, 3),
        ("Cricket", "Cricket", 3, 3),
        ("Basketball", "Soccer", 3, 3),
    ],
)

def get_columns_updates(row: pd.Series) -> str:
    """Returns string with names of updated columns or 'No update'"""
    updates = []
    if row["updated_hobby"] != row["old_hobby"]:
        updates.append("Hobby")
    if row["updated_skill"] != row["old_skill"]:
        updates.append("Skill")
    return ", ".join(updates) or "No update"


df["columns_updated"] = df.apply(get_columns_updates, axis=1)
```